# How i can reverse mysqli querie's result order

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I don't know the title is relevant enough or not..
 Here's the thing i wanna do

i have a table (tbl_users) with two columns

```
id(Primary)
name(varchar)
```

with entries..Like this...

when i execute this query

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_users order by id desc limit 3");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row["id"]."<br>";
}
```

and i get these results

- 7
- 6
- 5

But I want result in this order

- 5
- 6
- 7

Comment: Perhaps in your sql query the `orderBy` should be `asc` (or removing the  `desc` should also do it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

According to your comment, here another try:

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) as r ORDER BY id asc");
```

Comment: Oh now I see what you want. Well, you can add an offset to the query. Are these 3 results the last 3 results in your table?

Comment: @twinfirends but i want entries in the sort of latest

Comment: @PrinceArora Try it with the new query. Just edited my answer.

Comment: @PrinceArora you need to post question precisely, and Twinfriends nice answ

Comment: @Twinfriends it worked fine but can u exaplain what 'r' means in query

Comment: @PrinceArora Its an alias. You can remove the `as r` part if you want and it will still return the result. If you want to learn more about aliases simply google for `SQL alias`

Answer (score 0):

when you are using order by in mysql you write column for order and (ASC or DESC)

ASC-ascending

DESC- desceding

if you dont put asc or desc, default is asc, in your case its like this

```
ORDER BY id or
ORDER BY id ASC

$result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_users order by id asc limit 3 OFFSET 4");
```

Comment: This still won't work. Offset counts from the beginning of the table, not from the end.

Comment: I saw now, he didnt post question precisely what he need @Twinfriends, nice answ

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`$result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_users order by id ASC limit 3 OFFSET 4");`